# how to check if substring has a same value in same input using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a hidden input with different values. I want when checkbox is unchecked to remove-replace value.

```
<input id="test" type="hidden" name="test" value="4220752209,4220752209,4220752094,4220752094">
```

I Have a table in whose first column I have a checkbox. 
Every time when I click I get the hidden value and store it in input like this

```
if ($("#test").val() == '') {
    //this is my data aData.ordercode
    $("#test").val(aData.ordercode);
} else {
    $('#test').val($('#test').val() + "," + aData.ordercode);
}
```

Now I want when I unchecked from table to find and replace the same value if you see my value has same numbers i want when uncheck a checkbox to find and I have doing like this

```
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        if ($("#test").val().indexOf(aData.ordercode) > -1) {
            alert("Yes");

        }
```

Comment: your question is kinda unclear. I still don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: do you know that you are adding the `checked` attribute agan?

Comment: Do you want to replace all occurrences `,` to `:` ?

Comment: hello i want to find and replase same value in same input , when i click unchecked to remove same value, because now when i checked or unchecked add with my code every time same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try these code :-

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4220752209"/> 
    <input id="test" type="hidden" name="test" value="4220752209,4220752219,4220752095,4220752096"/>
    $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click',function(){
       val = $(this).val();
       if($(this).is(':checked')) {
          var temp_array = $("#test").val().split(",");
          temp_array = jQuery.grep(temp_array, function(value) {
             return value != val;
          });
          $("#test").val(temp_array.join());

       }
       else {
         $("#test").val($("#test").val()+","+val);
       }
    });
```